# Do-while loop keeps repeating

Tags: c

Can you please tell me why this loop keeps repeating without letting me read `n`?

```
int n;
do
{
    printf("Height: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
}
while(n < 0 || n > 23);
```

I can't enter any value because "Height: " keeps repeating. Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    do
    {
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    while(n < 0 || n > 23);

    for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j < n - i - 1;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",' ');
        }
        for(k=0;k < i + 2;k++)
        {
            printf("%c",'#');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "letting me read n"? The code asks to enter a height and if it is negative or larger than 23 it asks again, else it stops.

Comment: @0RedDevil0 What did you enter?

Comment: It will improve your chances of getting a useful reply if you make clear to your readers what problem you are having.  It's not clear what your code is doing (or not doing) that is different from your expectations.  Reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might give you some ideas.

Comment: A non-integer input (e.g. letter or string) will cause an infinite loop (with no further blocks at the `scanf`). Because a non-integer input will cause `scanf` to immediately and continuously return an error code since `scanf` has been told to accept only a single integer.

Comment: @PieterBruegeltheElder I can't enter any value.."Height: " keeps repeating

Comment: @0RedDevil0 Please tell us how you are launching/running the program. If you just run it directly from the command line it should always block on `scanf` for at least the first time. There's nothing in your code that would cause that not to happen. So perhaps it is in the way you are running it.

Comment: @AlanAu I build the program in Sublime Text 3. I also just created a new C build system using minGW compiler. I'm a complete beginner so I hope it makes sense what I'm saying.

Comment: @0RedDevil0 That's how you build it. But how do you run it after the build?

Comment: @AlanAu I discovered the problem. I just found and ran the executable and it works. I've previously worked in Gedit on Linux and the program ran in the terminal. So I thought Sublime Text does the same...but it kept repeating "Height: " in a tab under my code which I think is not the same terminal tab as in Gedit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @0RedDevil0 Glad you sorted that out. But please do take note of some of the answers and comments anyway as they do point out important problems with the way you are currently using `scanf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the return of scanf. In this case if scanf is successful, it will return 1. If it does not return 1 then an invalid input was made such as `www` for an int. In that case, clear the buffer and try again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = -1;

    do {
        printf ( "height \n");
        if ( scanf ( "%d", &i) != 1) {// != 1 means scanf failed
            while ( ( i = getchar()) != '\n' && i != EOF) {
                ;//clear buffer
            }
            i = -1;
        }
    } while ( i < 0 || i > 23);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that somewhere along the line, you should handle EOF so that the outer loop exits on EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your value for n is greater than 23, that loop will print on forever.  I'm also wondering if your first conditional n < 0 is providing the condition "is false" or "is greater than 23." You should try logging n to see what it's being provided to your loop as, and if it's greater than 23, maybe set an upper bounds for your loop.